# Detecting mobile device in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, analytics

Anyone know if it's possible to track the specific device (e.g iPhone 6) and specific OS (e.g. iOS 9) users are using? We'd like to send this data to our analytics package Mixpanel.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Add below line of code in any of your controller file,

**Controller**

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
     //find device details
     if (window.cordova) {
         var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
         var cordova = $cordovaDevice.getCordova();
         var model = $cordovaDevice.getModel();
         var platform = $cordovaDevice.getPlatform();
         var platformVersion = $cordovaDevice.getVersion();
         var mobileDetails = {
             'uuid': uuid,
             'cordova': cordova,
             'model': model,
             'platform': platform,
             'platformVersion': platformVersion,
         };
         console.log('Mobile Phone details:', mobileDetails)
     }
 });
```

`mobileDetails` contains all the details about device